# How to display log messages in xcode 4.2.1 consol window

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

After upgrading to xcode 4.2.1 on lion, I tried to do `NSLog(@"testing...");` but it's not displayed in the console window (debug area), why ?

p.s. I chose this option from console: All .. which is supposed to mean to display all messages...

Comment: means your code was not executed.

Comment: @mandeepd +1, for being funny. :P

Comment: are you seeing in the console ... ?? press command + shift + c to see the console

Comment: is your breakpoint coming there?

Comment: loool this is really funny ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the right panel of the debug area was hidden to the right direction.